# How can I tell if an installed cert is wildcard or not

Tags: ssl-certificate, certbot, wildcard-subdomain

I installed a cert for my server a while ago using certbot, and cant remember if I setup as a wildcard or not, What command can I run to see if it is or not?

Comment: Which server, exactly?

Comment: An apache webserver I am running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run (replacing `www.example.com` with your own hostname)

```
SERVERNAME=www.example.com; echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $SERVERNAME:443 -servername $SERVERNAME 2>/dev/null| grep subject | grep -o "CN=.*"
```

then you'll either see `CN=www.example.org` (no wildcard) or `CN=*.example.org` (a wildcard cert)

Comment: IF you are feelign saucy, please see my next question at:  https://serverfault.com/questions/1101249/certbot-wildcard-cert-not-a-wildcard

Comment: Yup! Just did :)

Comment: you are my guardian angel today!  thanks a ton for both