# certbot wildcard cert not a wildcard

Tags: ssl-certificate, certbot

I did the following:

```
sh-3.2# certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --email admin@example.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d *.someDomainlab.com
```

and got results:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Press Enter to Continue

Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/someDomainlab.com/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/someDomainlab.com/privkey.pem
This certificate expires on 2022-08-16.
These files will be updated when the certificate renews.
```

however when i test wildcard based on [This link](https://serverfault.com/questions/1101236/how-can-i-tell-if-an-installed-cert-is-wildcard-or-not/1101246#1101246), i get the following result:

```
CN=someDomainlab.com
```

which tells me its not wildcard.  I did a dig on _acme-challenge.someDomainlab.com and that returned what certbot told me to add.

what am i missing?

edit:

in the ssl_error.log i see this line when i do the command to test:

```
[Wed May 18 12:52:23.763857 2022] [core:debug] [pid 7607] protocol.c(1447): [client 192.168.183.1:51660] AH00566: request failed: malformed request line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the domain, so the shell doesn't try and expand the asterisk in `*.someDomainlab.com`. Use `-d '*.someDomainlab.com'` like this:

```
sh-3.2# certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --email admin@example.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d '*.someDomainlab.com'
```